# Unable to run behave from command line

Tags: python, python-behave

I'm trying to run behave from command line ( using cmder & sublime text 3), but im getting the following output

```
behave --name features\zero.feature
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\behave-script.py", line 9, in <module>
     load_entry_point('behave==1.2.5', 'console_scripts', 'behave')()
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\behave\__main__.py", line 111, in main
  File "c:\python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
      return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
  UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\ufffd' in position 31: character maps to <undefined>
```

Also i referred this [github thread](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/926), i'm not able to understand much.

Comment: Seems like your code may contain some characters that can't be understood.

Comment: @kindall, thanks for your response. The issue got fixed, i started my feature file with scenario directly, and then i included feature, and everything was good.